# Flash-cs5 vs flashcs5 vs adobe-flash-cs5?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, retag-request

These tags should all be mapped to a single master tag:

[flash-cs5](/questions/tagged/flash-cs5)

[flashcs5](/questions/tagged/flashcs5)

[adobe-flash-cs5](/questions/tagged/adobe-flash-cs5)

How do I do that? (Or can someone with the proper rep do it, please?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click the 'synonyms' link on one of the tag pages and follow the instructions.